# STSADM Command for Creating a Web Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, stsadm

i'm scripting (as much as possible) a MOSS 2007 environment migration.  i'm able to get most of it done using a batch file of STSADM commands, however, i'm unable to find an STSADM command to create a web application.  Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[stsadm -o extendvs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263040.aspx)

extendvs extends an existing web application, or creates a new web application if the web application does not exist.

I use this operation in my build scripts to create my web applications.

Example:

```
stsadm.exe -o extendvs -url %urlintranet% -ownerlogin %actintranet% -owneremail %intranetowner% -exclusivelyusentlm -databasename %dbcintranet% -donotcreatesite -apcreatenew -apidname %apintranet% -apidtype configurableid -apidlogin %actapintranet% -apidpwd %pwdapintranet% -description %intranetdesc%
```

To create your site collection, use [stsadm -o createsite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262594.aspx)

Comment: i like the idea of PowerShell, however, i think this is exactly what i was looking for.  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell may be a good alternative.  I believe it will replace stsadm in the next version of SharePoint.  Here's a good blog post with several PowerShell for SharePoint links: http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/bobmixon/archive/2008/08/15/powershell-and-sharepoint.aspx.